# Pandas to_datetime function resulting in Unix timestamp instead of Datetime for certain date strings

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am running into an issue where the Pandas to_datetime function results in a Unix timestamp instead of a datetime object for certain rows. The date format in rows that do convert to datetime and rows that convert to Unix timestamp as int appear to be identical. When the problem occurs it seems to affect all the dates in the row.

For example, :

`2019-01-02T10:12:28.64Z` (stored as str) ends up as `1546424003423000000`

While

`2019-09-17T11:28:49.35Z` (stored as str) converts to a datetime object.

Another date in the same row is `2019-01-02T10:13:23.423Z` (stored as str) which is converting to a timestamp as well.

There isn't much code to look at, the conversion happens on a single line:

`full_df.loc[mask, 'transaction_changed_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(full_df['SaleItemChangedOn'])` and

`full_df.loc[pd.isnull(full_df['completed_date']), 'completed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(full_df['SaleCompletedOn']`

I've tried with `errors='coerce'` on as well but the result is the same. I can deal with this problem later in the code, but I would really like to understand why this is happening.

**Edit**

As requested, this is the MRE to reproduces the issue on my computer. Some notes on this:

1. The mask is somehow involved. If I remove the mask it converts fine.
2. If I only pass in the first row in the Dataframe (single row Dataframe) it converts fine.

````py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import NaT, Timestamp

debug_dict = {'SaleItemChangedOn': ['2019-01-02T10:12:28.64Z', '2019-01-02T10:12:28.627Z'],
              'transaction_changed_datetime': [NaT, Timestamp('2019-01-02 11:58:47.900000+0000', tz='UTC')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(debug_dict)
mask = (pd.isnull(df['transaction_changed_datetime']))
df.loc[mask, 'transaction_changed_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SaleItemChangedOn'])```
````

Comment: Try specifying the format when you do `pd.to_datetime`. Currently you are letting pandas detects the format for you, but your date strings seem inconsistent.

Comment: This dataset is a merge of several different data sources. The date strings are inconsistent. That said, cosmic_inquiry asked for an MRE which I've added. While building that I discovered that if I don't include the `mask`, it converts fine. I.E, `df['transaction_changed_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SaleItemChangedOn']) ` converts just fine. I assume I'm doing something stupid with the mask, but I just can't see it.

Unfortunately I do need the mask as I only want to copy the data across in instances where `transaction_changed_datetime` is `NaT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug in Panda that has been fixed with the release of V1.0. The example code above now produces the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

When I try the examples you mention:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['2019-01-02T10:12:28.64Z', '2019-09-17T11:28:49.35Z', np.nan]})
pd.to_datetime(df['a'])
```

There doesn't seem to be any issue:

```
Out[74]: 
0   2019-01-02 10:12:28.640000+00:00
1   2019-09-17 11:28:49.350000+00:00
2                                NaT
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Could you provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thank you, building an MRE gave me some good insight into the problem. No solution, but I know that it's not the to_datetime function directly that is the problem. My use of a mask is somehow involved.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if you have more than one column with the same name which is being sent to pd.to_datetime. It solved the datetime being converted to timestamp problem for me.